# Converting list<string> to string or opposite

Tags: c#, xml

I'm working on a project were I'm trying to insert data from XML to Database table.

To do that I've created local variables and wants to insert the XML-tags into them so that I later can insert those local variables into the database.

The way I did it was to deserialize the XML:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                try
                {

                    List<FolkbokforingspostTYPE> deserializedList = new List<FolkbokforingspostTYPE>();
                    deserializedList = Deserialize<List<FolkbokforingspostTYPE>>();


                    var First = deserializedList.Select(item => item.Personpost.Namn.Fornamn).ToList();
                    foreach (var o in First)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Namn: " + o);
                    }

     //local variable that contains the the value of a XML tag.
     string FirstName = First;


                }
    PersonalIdentityNumber...  deserializedList contains everything if you need it
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            }



 private static T Deserialize<T>() where T : new()
    {
        // Create an instance of T
        T ReturnListOfT = CreateInstance<T>();


        // Create a new file stream for reading the XML file
        using (FileStream ReadFileStream = new FileStream("navetout.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            // Construct a XmlSerializer and use it  
            // to serialize the data from the stream.
            XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            try
            {
                // Deserialize the hashtable from the file
                ReturnListOfT = (T)SerializerObj.Deserialize(ReadFileStream);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Failed to serialize. Reason: {0}", ex.Message));
            }

        }
        // return the Deserialized data.
        return ReturnListOfT;
    }

    // function to create instance of T
    public static T CreateInstance<T>() where T : new()
    {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    }
```

**The problem** is that I can't convert the `list<string>` (that gets the value from the XML) to assign to a local variable.

From the above code you can see that I tried this:

```
string FirstName = First;
```

But I get error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'string'

I do know why I get the error, I'm just wondering if there is a way around it? Can I somehow assign a list to a local variable?

This is how I deserialized the XML:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Sekretessmarkering")]
public class Sekretessmarkering
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "nil", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Nil { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "PersonId")]
public class PersonId
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PersonNr")]
    public string PersonNr { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "HanvisningsPersonNr")]
public class HanvisningsPersonNr
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "nil", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Nil { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Mellannamn")]
public class Mellannamn
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "nil", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Nil { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Aviseringsnamn")]
public class Aviseringsnamn
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "nil", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Nil { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Namn")]
public class Namn
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Tilltalsnamnsmarkering")]
    public string Tilltalsnamnsmarkering { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Fornamn")]
    public string Fornamn { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Mellannamn")]
    public Mellannamn Mellannamn { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Efternamn")]
    public string Efternamn { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Aviseringsnamn")]
    public Aviseringsnamn Aviseringsnamn { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ForsamlingKod")]
public class ForsamlingKod
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "nil", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Nil { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Folkbokforing")]
public class Folkbokforing
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Folkbokforingsdatum")]
    public string Folkbokforingsdatum { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "LanKod")]
    public string LanKod { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "KommunKod")]
    public string KommunKod { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ForsamlingKod")]
    public ForsamlingKod ForsamlingKod { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Fastighetsbeteckning")]
    public string Fastighetsbeteckning { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "FiktivtNr")]
    public string FiktivtNr { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "CareOf")]
public class CareOf
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "nil", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Nil { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Utdelningsadress1")]
public class Utdelningsadress1
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "nil", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Nil { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Folkbokforingsadress")]
public class Folkbokforingsadress
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CareOf")]
    public CareOf CareOf { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Utdelningsadress1")]
    public Utdelningsadress1 Utdelningsadress1 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Utdelningsadress2")]
    public string Utdelningsadress2 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PostNr")]
    public string PostNr { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Postort")]
    public string Postort { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Riksnycklar")]
public class Riksnycklar
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "FastighetsId")]
    public string FastighetsId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AdressplatsId")]
    public string AdressplatsId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "LagenhetsId")]
    public string LagenhetsId { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Adresser")]
public class Adresser
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Folkbokforingsadress")]
    public Folkbokforingsadress Folkbokforingsadress { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Riksnycklar")]
    public Riksnycklar Riksnycklar { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "HemortSverige")]
public class HemortSverige
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "FodelselanKod")]
    public string FodelselanKod { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Fodelseforsamling")]
    public string Fodelseforsamling { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Fodelse")]
public class Fodelse
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "HemortSverige")]
    public HemortSverige HemortSverige { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Medborgarskap")]
public class Medborgarskap
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "MedborgarskapslandKod")]
    public string MedborgarskapslandKod { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Medborgarskapsdatum")]
    public string Medborgarskapsdatum { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Personpost")]
public class Personpost
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PersonId")]
    public PersonId PersonId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "HanvisningsPersonNr")]
    public HanvisningsPersonNr HanvisningsPersonNr { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Namn")]
    public Namn Namn { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Folkbokforing")]
    public Folkbokforing Folkbokforing { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Adresser")]
    public Adresser Adresser { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Fodelse")]
    public Fodelse Fodelse { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Medborgarskap")]
    public Medborgarskap Medborgarskap { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "FolkbokforingspostTYPE")]
public class FolkbokforingspostTYPE
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Sekretessmarkering")]
    public Sekretessmarkering Sekretessmarkering { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Personpost")]
    public Personpost Personpost { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: instead of `.ToList()` did u try `FirstOrDefault()`?

Comment: Well, it contains multiple values and if I try `FirstOrDefault()` then it only returns the first letter of the value..

Comment: It would be a good idea to start debugging. Verify that that `Deserialize` really is returning a list of `FolkbokforingspostTYPE`, and not (for example) null.

Comment: Didn't notice that comment ".. it only returns the first letter of the value" before. That's a big hint. You want a list there but there is a string. The only reason for you to see that behaviour would be if `deserializedList` was in fact a string. Which means that the problem is in your `Deserialize` method: it is returning a string despite you requesting a list of `FolkbokforingspostTYPE`. You need to debug that method.

Comment: I think it's the foreach loop that is causing only a letter to be written to the console, as it's looping over a string when you use FirstOrDefault()

Comment: @JanR Well when I loop with the loop I have now, I get the whole value from the XML(all the values), which is exactly what I want. 

My end goal is to insert these values into a database table, so if it is possible to insert a list into the database, I rather do that.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you just want to store the first names in a database? or do you want to store the whole object? Can you specify your requirements a bit more?

Comment: I want to store all values into the database. That means all the first names etc. But yeah, I want to store all the first names into the database. I suppose it's a list in that case.. Is it possible to insert a whole list into the database table?

Answer (score 0):

*Well, it contains multiple values and if I try FirstOrDefault() then it only returns the first letter of the value..*

From this comment it seems like your `List<string>` is holding single letters as items where all items together are building the word.

At this point your question about how to `List to string` makes a bit sense.

Instead of `string FirstName = First;`
use `string FirstName = String.Join("", First);`

`String.Join()` will join all of the items in the `List<string>` and return a `string`.

Comment: Thank you it it does work. However, as I said in the comments, my ultimate goal is to insert multiple values into the database, not just one string. That is the reason it had to be a list<string>. I can't just insert one big string and expect it to spread out on multiple columns in the database, it has to be a list so that the database know how to separate the values from each other and insert them in the database columns. My question had a very bad title, so I understand you guys got confused. I'm sorry

Comment: Dude: You want to store a list (multiple items) in a string-variable (single item) and then being able passing this single item to the database so the database recognizes it as a list? Are you serious???

Comment: No, I realized  that I was very stupid of me to store the list into a string. Right now I'm trying to figure out how to insert the list directly into the database, without a string.

Comment: Then this question isnt fitting your real goals. The topic, text and code isnt that much database-related. I would suggest to you deleting this question and going on with a new clean one. Maybe the easier way.

Comment: If you continue going with your problem in this question you will probably confuse people.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to load the xml that when deserialized returns a list of string and you want this list of string to be stored in the database BUT since list of string is not a data type that the database can handle you intend to store it as string.

As @C4ud3x said, string.Join will turn your list to a string. But I also assume you would want to convert this back to a list from the database for some scenario.

> Instead of string FirstName = First; use string FirstName =
>   String.Join("", First);

Change it to String.Join("*", First); where * is a special character you want to use to separate your data.

Ex: First = ['John','Doe','Foo','Bar'];

```
string FirstName = String.Join("*", First); //John*Doe*Foo*Bar
```

then store this to the database.

To convert it back to a list you can use string.Split

```
string[] First = FirstName.Split('*', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); //['John','Doe','Foo','Bar'];
```

Or you can serialize your data into JSON which is very easy to deserialize back to an object.

One database example that uses JSON only is [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/?gclid=CMG_4J6h-8sCFQyZvAodXM0NRA).